# vue js paginating css not as expected in documentation

Tags: vue.js

I am implementing this paginator in vue:
https://github.com/lokyoung/vuejs-paginate

For some weird reason the layout doesn't work, this is what my paginator looks like:

[image]

I imported and used it:

```
import Paginate from 'vuejs-paginate'
Vue.component('paginate', Paginate);
```

I did this in my html page where I use the component:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuejs-paginate@latest"></script>
```

In my component I did:

```
<paginate
  :page-count="31"
  :page-range="10"
  :maring-pages="5"
  :click-handler="pageClickCallback"
  :container-class="'pagination'"
/>
```

Everything as the documentation stated, but no layout.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, like this package is not providing CSS at all, you need to style it by yourself - or - use `bootstrap.css`. See their demo -https://jsfiddle.net/lokyoung/u3u3nzns/ if you remove boostrap.css (in resources tab) - you will see, that there are no styles applied.
You can see classes used here - https://github.com/lokyoung/vuejs-paginate/blob/master/src/components/Paginate.vue

Answer (score 0):

Current implementation of paginate expects classes from bootstrap.
Import css from bootstrap somewhere on the page

Then write below code to implement the paginate

```html
<paginate
    v-model="page"                
    :click-handler="changePage"
    :container-class="'pagination'"   
    :page-count="10"    
    :page-class="'page-item'"
    :next-class="'page-item'"
    :prev-class="'page-item'"
    :page-link-class="'page-link'"
    :prev-link-class="'page-link'"
    :next-link-class="'page-link'">
</paginate>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<paginate 
   v-model="page" 
   :page-count="20" 
   :prev-text="'Prev'"
   :next-text="'Next'" 
   :container-class="'pagination'" 
>
</paginate>

.pagination {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.pagination > li {
  display: inline;
}
.pagination > li > a,
.pagination > li > span {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #337ab7;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.pagination > li:first-child > a,
.pagination > li:first-child > span {
  margin-left: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
.pagination > li:last-child > a,
.pagination > li:last-child > span {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
.pagination > li > a:hover,
.pagination > li > span:hover,
.pagination > li > a:focus,
.pagination > li > span:focus {
  z-index: 3;
  color: #23527c;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-color: #ddd;
}
.pagination > .active > a,
.pagination > .active > span,
.pagination > .active > a:hover,
.pagination > .active > span:hover,
.pagination > .active > a:focus,
.pagination > .active > span:focus {
  z-index: 2;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #337ab7;
  border-color: #337ab7;
}
.pagination > .disabled > span,
.pagination > .disabled > span:hover,
.pagination > .disabled > span:focus,
.pagination > .disabled > a,
.pagination > .disabled > a:hover,
.pagination > .disabled > a:focus {
  color: #777;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ddd;
}
.pagination-lg > li > a,
.pagination-lg > li > span {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.3333333;
}
.pagination-lg > li:first-child > a,
.pagination-lg > li:first-child > span {
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}
.pagination-lg > li:last-child > a,
.pagination-lg > li:last-child > span {
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}
.pagination-sm > li > a,
.pagination-sm > li > span {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.pagination-sm > li:first-child > a,
.pagination-sm > li:first-child > span {
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}
.pagination-sm > li:last-child > a,
.pagination-sm > li:last-child > span {
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
```